# Can I connect the supply ground wire to a fixture's ground wire with a wire nut

Tags: wiring, grounding

Supply has black, white and ground wires. Light fixture has black and white wires and a green screw for ground. Green screw connects to fixture itself. I cannot get the supply ground around the fixture's green ground screw and the ground is short to begin with. Can I get another ground wire, connect  it to fixture's green ground screw and then wire nut the two grounds together?

Comment: Is the junction box in the ceiling made of metal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. What you propose is safe, code compliant, and good workmanship.

Electrical codes in most locations require that a ground fault wire be either bare (uninsulated), insulated in green, or insulated in green and yellow stripes.